# Facebook graph v2.0, search/query by geographical location

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Searching for posts close to a location in facebook graph api:**

In graph api v1.0 you would run something like this query:
[https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=[LAT,LON]&distance=[RADIUS]&fields=status&limit=15&access_token=[TOKEN]](https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=%5bLAT,LON%5d&distance=%5bRADIUS%5d&fields=status&limit=15&access_token=%5bTOKEN%5d)

As I understand v1.0 of the graph api will expire in april 2015.

How, if possible, can I do a similar search/query in v2.0 to get posts/statuses/photo posts/checkins close to a location.
Has anyone done some digging into this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the ChangeLog searching for public posts will no longer be available in v2.0:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api (section "Endpoints no longer available in v2.0")

> Public Post search is no longer available.
>   (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

Coming back to your question, the search call you posted will search for LOCATIONS, not posts.

Comment: The search call I posted will in v1 search for posts/statuses with location on them.